# why is this worker/ thread not stopping?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a panel which has a several comboboxes in it and a button to close the panel. I set up the comboboxes to get populated with another thread because it has many entries. So the background worker starts and everything goes as expected until you close the panel. If I close the panel before the background worker is finished, I get an error. Let me explain:

I start the process of by starting the background worker:

```
get_info.RunWorkerAsync()
```

The close button sub looks like this:

```
Private Sub close_everything()

   ' dispose of the panel that holds the comboboxes
   info_panel.dispose()

   ' tell the background worker to stop working
   get_info.CancelAsync()

End Sub
```

I set up the background worker like this:

```
   Private Sub getInfo_doWork()
      'populate the combo boxes
      populate_last_names()        
   End Sub
```

Then the subroutine to populate the last name looks like this:

```
Private Sub populate_last_names()
    ' get the names
      get_names()

     ' since the combobox control is in another thread, I need to use the Invoke method to access it
     ' put them in the combobox
     for a as integer = 0 to last_names.count - 1
         last_name_box.Invoke(Sub() last_name_box.Items.Add(last_names(a)))
     next
End Sub
```

When the close button is pressed, I get an error stating that the combobox has been disposed. So I added a check for the background worker first. So my code changed to:

```
     ' put them in the combobox
     for a as integer = 0 to last_names.count - 1
         if not(get_info.CancellationPending) then
           last_name_box.Invoke(Sub() last_name_box.Items.Add(last_names(a)))
         end if
     next
```

but I still got the same error, so I added another check and changed the code to this:

```
     ' put them in the combobox
     for a as integer = 0 to last_names.count - 1
         if not(get_info.CancellationPending) then
           if not(last_name_box.IsDisposed) then
             last_name_box.Invoke(Sub() last_name_box.Items.Add(last_names(a)))
           end if
         end if
     next
```

and I STILL get an error stating that the last_name box has been disposed, if I close the panel before the loop is finished.

The error even states that the value of last_name_box.IsDisposed is TRUE and the value of CancellationPending is TRUE. So why is it executing the next line if it is TRUE?

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: I think the error is because you're trying to dispose something that is already disposed (i.e. the problem lies in `close_everything`). Can you confirm which scope the exception is arising in?

Comment: The close_everything sub only gets called once. The error is on the line where I am trying to add an item to the combobox. The specific error is: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ComboBox'. and it points to the line in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the background worker first:

```
Private Sub close_everything()

   ' tell the background worker to stop working
   get_info.CancelAsync()

   ' dispose of the panel that holds the comboboxes
   info_panel.dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: The background worker is stopped in the close_everything Subroutine. That is what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is badly constructed.  What you should be doing is getting the data in the DoWork event handler and then passing it to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler via the e.Result property.  You then populate the controls with the data in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, which is executed on the UI thread.

You should also not be hiding the Panel anywhere but in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  You request cancellation from the UI thread and then you actually perform the cancellation in the DoWork event handler.  In the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, you check whether the operation was cancelled or not.  If it was then you simply hide the Panel, otherwise you populated the list(s).

Comment: The whole issue arose because adding 27,000 names to a combobox on the same thread as the UI hangs the interface too long for most people. That's why I need to do the actual populating of the list in another thread. Getting the names is fast compared to populating the combobox.

Comment: Rubbish.  You have no choice but to add the names to the ComboBox on the UI thread, as you yourself have shown.  What do you think Invoke does?  It marshals a method call to the the thread that owns the control you call it on, i.e. to the UI thread.  What you should be doing is calling AddRange once rather than Add over and over in a loop.  In fact, by calling Invoke in a loop you are making everything take far longer because there is an overhead associated with doing so.  Apart from that, a single list with 27,000 items?  Not a great UX I'm afraid.

Comment: Just a thought - if the combobox is not visible at the time entries are added, and it has no parent or owner at that time, is there any messaging done?  You could maybe create a combobox instance, signal it to the thread, fill it, message it back and display it back in the main thread?  Dunno - never tried it:)

Comment: Thanks Martin, but the combo box is visible at the time. I'm not sure how you would go about doing that. I'm still looking for alternatives at the moment.

Comment: Why are you still looking for alternatives?  You already know what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since a viable answer to my problem did not seem possible, I ended up switching to a textbox with autofill instead of a combobox with autofill. I was just using the combo box because of the autofill capability and didn't realize the textbox could do the same thing. The data is gathered in the background worker and the source for the autofill is assigned after the data is collected in the main UI. I couldn't accomplish exactly what I wanted so I settled for this. There is still some delay but it is manageable.